# Multidimensional array, find item and move to the top?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to do some kind of function that will find (in the following array) the object with the id of 2, and move it to the top of the array. Here's the original array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 177
            [startdate] => 2014-08-02
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 178
            [startdate] => 2014-08-02
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [startdate] => 2014-07-28
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 82
            [startdate] => 2014-07-28

        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 199
            [startdate] => 2013-10-10
        )
)
```

And here is what I'd like it to output (with the moved array item):

```
Array
(

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [startdate] => 2014-07-28
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 177
            [startdate] => 2014-08-02
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 178
            [startdate] => 2014-08-02
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 82
            [startdate] => 2014-07-28

        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 199
            [startdate] => 2013-10-10
        )
)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just realised that the array key is also 2, I don't want it to move that, I need it to move the one which is [id] => 2..

Comment: Do not edit question in the comments, put your edit up in the question. What have you tried already?

Comment: Compare (when there is no need to look inside the inner array): http://stackoverflow.com/a/27217431/1333493

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
function customShift($array, $id){
    foreach($array as $key => $val){     // loop all elements
        if($val->id == $id){             // check for id $id
            unset($array[$key]);         // unset the $array with id $id
            array_unshift($array, $val); // unshift the array with $val to push in the beginning of array
            return $array;               // return new $array
        }
    }
}

print_r(customShift($data, 2));
```

Comment: break from foreach when you found the record OR fix the code, so the $out array can have multiple rows, and multiple rows can be unshifted.

Comment: I agree that ID should be unique, but you never know what people are trying to do, thats why I have made OR proposal ;-) p.s. You can make your code even smaller by 2 lines, remove $out variable, and move unshift where you set $out.

Comment: Do you think we can make it even smaller? ;-) Just joking. +1

Comment: This works well! when you do array_unshift it moves the array on the top of the array you want thanks +1