# php Need to move one element at top of array

Tags: php, arrays

Have array like this

```
Array
(
[] => 
[3837920201e05ba7c2fbffd3f1255129] => 'bg img a href Main | Delete etc'
[94ae40ff9b6df5bb123fb12211f48b11] => 'bg img a href Main | Delete etc'
[3974b3863e7ca7b7ea2026e44bbacfd2] => 'bg img a href Main | Delete etc'
)
```

Want to move key `3974b3863e7ca7b7ea2026e44bbacfd2` at top so array would look like

```
Array
(
[] => 
[3974b3863e7ca7b7ea2026e44bbacfd2] => 'bg img a href Main | Delete etc'
[3837920201e05ba7c2fbffd3f1255129] => 'bg img a href Main | Delete etc'
[94ae40ff9b6df5bb123fb12211f48b11] => 'bg img a href Main | Delete etc'
)
```

At first extract item that i want to be at top

```
$top_image = array_slice( $array, 2, 1 );
```

`3974b3863e7ca7b7ea2026e44bbacfd2` is third element (as if key) in array (0,1,2)

Next want to create array `$other_images`. Decided to remove the initial third element and then merge both arrays.

Trying to remove third element. Read `[array_splice][1]` understand that first number (offset) is where i want to start to remove and second (length) - how many elements want to remove. So I tried

```
$top_image = array_splice( $array, 2, 1 );
```

But result is the same as with array_slice.

Then tried

```
foreach( $arr as $k => $val ){
   if( $k != 2 ){
      $other_images[] = $val;
   }
}
```

Expect to see 2 remaining elements. But see all 3.

What is wrong? How to remove certain element from array?

Regarding `foreach` `$k` can not be equal to 2, because `$k` is the long string... Tried `for`, but also not suitable...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to move the last element into the first place use array_pop, array_merge and a foreach trick to keep the key.

```
foreach($array as $key => $v) {}
$temp = [$key => array_pop($array)];
array_merge($temp, $array);
$array = $temp;
```

If it's not the last element and you know the key, it's unset that will help you.

```
// assume $key is set
$temp = [$key => $array[$key]];
unset($array[$key]);
array_merge($temp, $array);
$array = $temp;
```

Comment: Not the last. And key is dynamic (i can not predict what would be value of a key). I am trying `$key_main_image = key($main_image)` and then `unset( $initial_array[$key_main_image] )` but something wrong...

Comment: @user2118559 ok, key is dynamic. But what you want to get? Element by "position"?

Comment: Just want to move one element of array at top of array. Seems no easy solution in such a way. So i decided to recode some part of code to get solution in another way. All this is related with situation when user uploads some images, then want to set one image as main. In such case i need to move the main image at the top. But i recoded some part of code and found solution in another way.

Answer (score 1):

Last elem ( `3974b3863e7ca7b7ea2026e44bbacfd2 => 'bg img a href Main | Delete etc'` ) to top:

```
  // last value to top
  $last = array_pop($arr); 
  array_unshift($arr,$last);
```

**Update**

```
  // last couple(key-value) to top
  end($arr);     
  $last_key = key($arr);
  $last_value = array_pop($arr); 
  $arr = array($last_key=>$last_value) + $arr;
  var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: Except that the key will be lost. '3974b3863e7ca7b7ea2026e44bbacfd2' is a key, not a value.

Comment: Yes, it is a key, not value. And not always the last element.

Comment: @voodoo417 But it not always the last element. It may be for example second element...