# Compare multidimensional array with each other and some array field with external variable

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like below. I need to compare with each other and return the matching array on the first index and followed by other.

How can we compare whole array each other based on id and scid with $scid?

```
$scid = 307;
$array = array(
    0 =>
        array(
            'id' => '485',
            'scid' => 306
        ),
    1 =>
        array(
            'id' => '484',
            'scid' => null
        ),
    2 =>
        array(
            'id' => '486',
            'scid' => 305
        ),
    3 =>
        array(
            'id' => '485',
            'scid' => 307
        ),
    4 =>
        array(
            'id' => '485',
            'scid' => 309
        ),
    5 =>
        array(
            'id' => '485',
            'scid' => 329
        ),
);
```

The result array should be like

```
 array(3) { 
             [485]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "485" ["scid"]=> int(307) } 
             [484]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "484" ["scid"]=> NULL } 
             [486]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "486" ["scid"]=> int(305) } 
        }
```

If array has duplicate id on which scid is not matching then we can pick any id value.
Note :The matching sub array should always be the first index of resulting array.An amount will always be unique and might contain null as well in array.

Comment: Well you have done all the analysis. Now you just need to code something to do it.

Comment: *duplicate id on which scid is not matching then we can pick any id value* - we can capture the first occured value, right? like `[485]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "485" ["scid"]=> int(306)` (first amoung `485`)

Comment: In the above scenario 485 has matching 307, so it must return
 [485]=> array(2) { ["id"]=> string(3) "485" ["scid"]=> int(307).
If it doesnot have that matching then it can pick any one with id 485. 
Also the one with matching scid should always be in first index.

Comment: I found a solution on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559878/multidimensional-array-find-item-and-move-to-the-top

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$temp = [];
    foreach($array as $k => $v){
        $temp[$v['id']][] = $v;
    }
```

Give it a try, this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $result[$item['id']] = ['id' => $item['id'], 'scid' => $item['scid']];
}
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Not really, , it doesnot have any comparision withe the $scid variable.It will just remove the duplicate but not have an array with matching $scid.

Comment: I have a solution to compare values, but I dont know how to keep the matching subarray always on the top.

$scid=307;
$result = [];
 for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++){
            if (!array_key_exists($array[$i]['id'], $result)|| $result[$array[$i]['id']]['scid'] != $scid)
            {
                $result[$array[$i]['id']] = $array[$i];
            }
        }