# move a specific subarray to the top of a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of rows (from a mysql table)
And need to `move` to the top a subarray - i.e. a row - having id = `$x`
Tried a modified solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12559878/) - without success

```
$st = $db->prepare("select id, nick from presto where id < 4");
$st->execute();
$rows = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($rows);
```

**result**

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 52 [nick] => 5fb63a1a8bcbf ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 54 [nick] => 5fb63a1a75171 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 59 [nick] => 5fb63a1a91e68 ) )`

```
$x = 54;

foreach($rows as $key => $val){
    if($key['id'] == $x){  // line 155
        unset($rows[$key]);
        array_unshift($rows, $val);
    }
}
```

and getting Warning - `Trying to access array offset on value of type int on line 155`

please help

Comment: Can you please check this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312879/moving-array-element-to-top-in-php

Comment: A query with "where id < 4" can never give a result like you show. If you want to exclude certain id you can already do that with SQL "NOT IN".

Comment: @jspit - are you sure ? I'm getting rows having `id` as `1`, `2`, or `3`. What's the problem ?

Comment: And where does the ID 54 that you want to bring to the top come from? Sample data and code are inconsistent.

Comment: @jspit - you're right, that's a mistake, but it's already solved, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$key on line 155 is the index/iteration/position in the array/foreach, which is an integer, not an array. $val is your data array from each iteration.

Try this.

```
$x = 54;

foreach($rows as $key => $val){
    if($val['id'] === $x){  // line 155
        unset($rows[$key]);
        array_unshift($rows, $val);
    }
}
```